# Android Studio - input text into editor

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to put some code into a java file in Android Studio's text editor. When I push the [ENTER] button to create some space for my text the next line is highlighted. Then I push it again and it highlights more script. It is like the [ENTER] button in the text editor is like pushing CONTROL+SHIFT in a word document, all it does is highlight stuff. I just want the [ENTER] button to work regularly in the text editor and create a break in the paragraph, like this:

This is an example of my struggles
ENTER (gives me some space)
ENTER (gives me more space)
But I am at a loss as to what I should do. Can someone please help!!!

Comment: Try Shift+Enter. Also, there may be a functional difference between the keys marked "Return" (usually the larger one on your keyboard) and "Enter" (usually the one in the numeric pad). If you are consistently trying only one of them, then try the other for a chance.

Comment: Could you please share an example what you're seeing? It may be a bit difficult to understand what is going on otherwise.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of your editor to understand the problem ?

Comment: Maybe check your key bindings, to make sure that enter has not been mistakenly assigned to some other editor action. I'm not sure if it is possible to assign enter to actions, but it is worth checking out. Alternately, try selecting one of the predefined key sets and see if that changes the behavior. Finally, ensure that the keyboard settings for your OS is correct (using an mismatched locale can sometimes have strange effects).

Comment: Hey guys, appreciate all of your remarkably smart answers, despite my confusing question. I should have mentioned I was using the text editor and was unable to insert code. I found out that if I click on the previous line and push enter then I'm able to insert code. I am now using Intel XDK and their "Use App Starter" program. This program is designed to create a very basic app with little to no code experience. Intel is really awesome for making this available.